# animate the images container to the position where is going to be on fullview

Tags: jquery

i have the below code from a tutorial ([link attached](http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenGridPortfolioTemplate/)) and the image container is animated to a middle right position!
But i want it to be bottom left! Whatever i was trying is wrong or not reproducable on another screen size! It makes no sense to me at all!
Please help!!

```
// animate the images container to the position where is going to be on fullview
var thumbsstyle     = {
    left    : $(window).width() - $thumbsWrapper.width() - 25 + 'px',  // 25 is the margin left / right of the fullview thumbs-wrapper
    top: ($(window).height() / 2) - ($thumbsWrapper.height() / 2) - 22 + 'px' // 10 is the margin top / bottom of the fullview thumbs-wrapper
};
$thumbsWrapper.stop().applyStyle( thumbsstyle, $.extend( true, [], { duration : animspeed, easing : animeasing} ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just make `left` as `0` and `bottom` as `0` that should do it.

#### Untested code

```
var thumbsstyle = {
    left: 0
    bottom: 0
};
$thumbsWrapper.stop().applyStyle(thumbsstyle, $.extend(true, [], {
    duration: animspeed,
    easing: animeasing
}));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Atif! left:0 works out fine, but with bottom:0 it still stays in top position! Anyway you half made my day!

Comment: Great! Now remove `top` in case its added

Comment: var thumbsstyle = {
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0
};    is what i got! Somehow it doesnt want to move to the bottom!

Comment: Is the `position` of its parent `relative`?

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenGridPortfolioTemplate/    thats where i got the inspiration from..